# Allow users to enter new value in Spinner

Tags: android, android-widget

First of all, I am new to android development. I am building a small application which contains a spinner in it's UI which has predefined set (array) of four numbers and I am using `ArrayAdapter` to feed the value to spinner from a resource file.

The spinner is working fine and users can select the values . But I also want users be able to enter new value if they wish to enter a new value. How would I do this?

**Codes in onCreate Method of Activity**:

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.points_preset, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());`

**Code for SpinnerActivity Class:**

**UPDATED to include input dialog:**

```
    public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, 
                int pos, long id) {
            if (pos==3)
            {
                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                            .setMessage("Enter your Point here")
                    .setView(input)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                          Editable   editable = input.getText(); 
                          //if I uncomment following line, the application terminates
                       // Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

                         }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                // Do nothing.
                         }
                    }).show(); 
            }

                                    }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    }
                    `
```

**Strings.xml resource file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">PointCalculator</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string-array name="points_preset">
    <item>3</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>Oth</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Updated and working version of SpinnerActivity Class

`

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, 
                        int pos, long id) {
                    if (pos==3)
                    {
                        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                                    .setMessage("Enter your Point here")
                            .setView(input)
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                  Editable   editable = input.getText(); 


                           arrayList.add(editable.toString());
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                 }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        // Do nothing.
                                 }
                            }).show(); 
                    }

                                            }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // Another interface callback
                }
            }`
```

Thanks,

Comment: This may depend where you getting the original values from. And show your code please.

Comment: @wtsang02, Codes are in place now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are creating the ArrayAdapter won't allow you to add to the array very easily since the backing array will be created from the resources.

First load the array from resources and add it to a List. Then create the ArrayAdapter using that List.

You can then add an item to the spinner by adding to the backing List. You will need to call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter to let it know that you changed the available items in the adapter.

Comment: Hi @Nick, I have changed the way the items are loaded to the spinner as you suggested. Now, how can I add new item to the spinner?

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do this. One way we do it is to have a `spinner` item that says something like "add item". In the `onItemSelected` we have an `AlertDialog` that pops up with an `EditText` for entering the item then you just add that to your `Array` or whatever you are using. You could also just have an `EditText` next to the `Spinner` or wherever for them to add new items then when they click a `Button` you add that to wherever your data is stored and call `notfiyDataSetChanged()` to update the `Spinner`. I hope this answered your question

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic! I liked the idea of showing `AlertDialog` with `EditText` on it. I will give it a try.

Comment: hi @codeMagic, Can you please have a look at my updated question. I have included the updated code for SpinnerActivity. I am able to get the value what is entered in the dialog box box still wondering how would I add it to the spinner? Thanks,

Comment: @BishnuPaudel you just need to add the text they enter into the `String Array` you use for your `adapter` then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Like @Nick said,  the arrayAdapter I created did not allow me to add new item easily. I have worked out by combining your and his answers. Thanks,